# Submit button value not changing with css

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to add some css to the value of a submit button. The only problem is that it won't listen to certain attributes. Changing the size of the font works fine, but I am trying to make it `font-weight: 300;` and it does not change the text. Is there any way to get this to work?

here is the html: yes, the submit button is outside the `container` on purpose.

```
<section id="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <form id="contact-form" action="contact.php" method="post" class="contact">
            <input id="sendername" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" />
            <input id="senderemail" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
            <textarea id="sendermessage" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send." />
        </form>
</section>
```

and here is the css: its compiled using SASS.

```
#contact {
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: $bgDark;
    @extend .master-padding;

    #contact-form {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #submit {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 40px;
        border: none;
        color: $colorLight;
        font-weight: 300;
        @extend .action;

        &:hover {
            color: $colorDark;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify, do you understand that `font-weight: 300` is normal font?  Most fonts only have two or three font weights they can be set at.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand actually i think `font-weight: 400;` is normal. 300 is the same as `font-weight: light;` because I'm using Open Sans

Comment: It looks like your html is not valid. You have `<div><form></div></form>`.

Comment: @Omada i know that is the only way i was able to get the submit button to go full width while staying within the form tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify the `font-weight`, it assumes 400.

Fonts that provide a light variant, usually require 100/200 (numbers by experience, not spec).  Bold is typically 600, and extra bold is usually 900.

Instead of numbers, try using one of the words from the [**`font-weight` spec**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-boldness), which include `normal` (400), `bold` (700), or `lighter`.  If you specify `lighter` and the `font-weight` would be `500` or less if unspecified, it will be treated as `100` or light weight.

Or use the value `100` which is the lightest font of the family, that's available.

#### Limitations:

If the user has no light font for the `font-family`, it will default to the lightest (usually the same as `normal`).

Comment: 1+ Good info! I didn't know this.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand actually what was weird is that I had to specify the font family again. Its already specified but for some reason it did not take it. After adding `font-family: Open Sans` it worked. Weird because i already defined the family in the html

Comment: @zachstarnes that happens to me in the `a` elements too! I only put `font: inherit` to fix it =).

Comment: That's probably browser styles interfering.  I recommend finding a good CSS reset/normailzer (they're varied in extremeness, from effectively having `inline` and `block` elements, to just removing default `padding`/`margin`; shop around).

Answer (score 3):

Just to be clear the answer I accepted was part correct. The other part was that I had to add `font-family: Open Sans` to the css. The weird thing is, is that I already specified it in the html tag in the css. I do not know why I had to do it again.

Comment: This was the problem for me. For some reason `input[type=submit]` doesn't apply the `font-family` given to its parent element. I think this is just for custom fonts but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FrC6T/)

```
#submit {
    font: 300 40px Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: @IeoMestizo not really. That is what it currently looks like. I am trying to change the font weight to 300 cause by default its 400

Comment: When I change the value 300 to 900, the font changes... Are you sure that 300 is lighten?

Comment: @IeoMestizo it does but when you do 300 it does not and that is what im trying to get to work. every other tag will change the font weight correctly but this won't for some reason

Answer (score 0):

you just add this next to your specified color **!important**

```
.button
{
 color:#000 !important; 
  }
```